# How to prove the condition for existence of solution of system of linear equations

Tags: linear-algebra

why does coefficient matrix and augmented matrix need to have the same rank for existence of solution of system of linear equations ?

Answer (score 1):

The rank of a matrix agrees with its column rank.  Hence, if you add a new column and the rank goes up, the new column was not in the columnspace of the previous ones.

Comment: how is existence of a solution related to this ?

Comment: A solution to $Ax=b$ can be thought of as a linear combination of the columns of $A$ to give the column $b$.